# Upgrade from 16.04 to 18.04.01 : August 6 - still "No new release found."

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade

**This is not a duplicate, because previously such question was asked at July 27. The answer was "only several hours passed, you should just wait". Now this answer does not fit.  The question is different when asked on August 6 than when it is asked on July 27.**

It is August 6, 12:15 UTC time.

I try to upgrade from 16.04.5 to 18.04.1, with do-release-upgrade, and receive "No new release found."

They said that the upgrade will be ready "several days" after 18.04.1 release.

The release was in June 26. It is August 6 now. 11 days passed. Several days?

So the question is, is it only my problem? Or it is a bug in do-release-upgrade?  Or they have a problem which they cannot solve yet, and I should just wait a bit more?

Comment: Try selecting "For any new version" for "Notify me of a new Ubuntu version" in Softwares & Updates instead of "For long-term support versions" only.

Comment: @pomsky Isn't it the same as do-release-upgrade -d ?

Comment: @pomsky - or they have a bug in do-release-upgrade, and what you suggest is workaround around it?

Comment: I'm not sure, if I'm not mistaken `-d` upgrades to the current development release, but this option looks for only stable versions.

Comment: Have just upgraded 16.04.5 to 18.04.1 having `prompt=lts` with `sudo do-release-upgrade -d`. It is unclear why it does not work without `-d`.

Comment: Unless we find someone here that actually works for Canonical and knows any reason why we are not getting the upgrade to 18.04.1 offers, I don't think we are going to find out here.  I have sent an email to Canonical asking them what the hold up is, but I have not heard anything back from them yet.  So, I understand the frustration here.  Not only doesn't `do-release-upgrade` without any switches not see an upgrade, neither does the `update-manager` which uses different code, so I don't think it is a bug.  I think it is not released yet, but for whatever reason, I simply don't know.

Comment: Alan Pope on a podcast (talking about one of the prior LTS upgrade paths) talked about this, this is not the first time, and occurs every two years. He referred to the enabling of the LTS to LTS upgrade as a 'tap' that is turned on when certain conditions and a decision is made inside Canonical (but did not say anything about what the makes up that decision, other than it relates to stability).  I've heard another Canonical employee refer to it as a "switch"; but either way I agree with Terrance, we don't know any more than we are told, and I suggest wait.  There is no security risk in waiting

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to do it with `sudo do-release upgrade -d` in two different computers, and got bad problems with Gnome.  In one computer, I was forced to reinstall everything.  So, the answer is: they are still solving problems with Unity to Gnome migration.

Answer (score 0):

I upgraded from 16.04 to 18.04.1 use command:

```
sudo do-release-upgrade -d
```

Before execute the command above, make sure you run:

```
sudo apt update
sudo apt upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
```